# screen -r spawning new prosses

Tags: mac-osx, gnu-screen

I'm new to screen and I'm trying to figure out how to detach from a session and reattach later. So far I've tried:

```
$screen
C-a z (within screen to detach)
$screen -r
```

So far so good but when I `C-a z` to detach again, I see 2 screen processes running:

```
$ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
33145 ttys000    0:00.06 -bash
33176 ttys000    0:00.01 screen
33407 ttys000    0:00.01 screen -r
```

If I detach and reattach again I get another screen process, etc...

So, how can I reattach to the screen session without spawning a new process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-a z` suspends your screen process. If your shell is bash, you can see the stopped process by running `jobs` and resume it with `fg`. Detaching is a different concept.

To detach from a session, use `C-a d`. You will still see the screen process in your process list, and you can list it by running `screen -ls`. Resume with `screen -r`, but read the man page about the different ways to resume a running screen session.

Congratulations on learning about screen! It's an amazing tool.

Comment: Thanks! screen really is amazing. I can't believe I'm just learning about it now. I ran across it while trying to find a way to do remote pair programming and now it's as ingrained in my development process as git.

Answer (score 6):

Try to detach within a screen:

```
ctrl a d
```

to reattach:

`screen -rd` (detaches the screen first if was attached)

There is also:

`screen -x`  (attaches the screen again, so you can watch the screen with two sessions)

Comment: To elaborate: `^A z` (or `^A ^Z`) ***suspends*** screen (the equivalent of `^Z` to most processes).  `^A d` (or `^A ^D`)is the Detach command.  To get back the screen session you suspended you need to use `fg` or other OS job control commands.